# Robot Cannot Find exe File

Tags: robotframework

I have a test that calls to executable file. that exec file gets a string and return another string.
for example:

```
cmd = "./myExecFile inputString"
out = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

when I ran it as python code it works well. the executable file run as expected and I get the right output string.
but when I ran it via robot test, for some reason I get the error message (the 'out' variable):
`./myExecFile not found`

that exec file located under the same folder where that robot file located:

```
|TestFolder
|----> myExecFile
|----> test.robot
```

I tried to add the path to robot by:

```
evaluate    sys.path.append(os.path.join("path", "to", "library"))    modules=os, sys
```

I printed the `sys.path` and verified that the path was added

but robot still cannot find `./myExecFile`

what am I missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: The `./` is most probably evaluated as the current working directory of the python interpreter, not as for the RF file's location. Try will it run properly with an absolute path, just as a test, and we'll take it from there; also to see what is the CWD, execute as an external process the `pwd` command (you're on some Linux flavor, right?).

Comment: thank you for he answer, I tried './absolute/path/myExecFile' and still get not found..

Comment: A path starting with `./` is still a relative one - from the current working directory. You need to try with `/path/starting/from/root/of/filesystem` - an absolute path from the root of your file system.

Comment: the absolute path working :) I also changed to pwd + concatenated 'myExecFile'. thank you!

Comment: @TodorMinakov: not just _most probably_ but _most definitiely_. `.` in a file path always means the current working directory.

Comment: @BryanOakley the "most probably" was for that it's the CWD of the interpreter, not the location of the suite file :) _(Which, thinking of it, I'm now 100% certain it's so - when being ran, a suite file is nothing more than text instructions, not direct code points. Thus CWD is the interpreter's one, and there's also the automatic variable `${SUITE SOURCE}` to be used for situations like in OP's question )_

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the absolute path
Or always execute the script from the same path (with cd nd robot in Terminal) and go from the path you execute from